# How to change title text font and color shown on casted image

Tags: react-native, casting, chromecast, google-cast

I have gone through the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver/customize_ui). Also created custom web receiver to achieve these kind of customizations but there is no proper documentation for casting images.

It has --font-family in customization parameters list but no mention of font size or text color.
So how do we change font and color of metadata(title and subtitle).

Comment: Google cast documentation is not very clear or helpful. I am still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at the moment we do not support modifying the font size or color of the metadata. If you would like to have this feature please do raise a feature request bug here: https://developers.google.com/cast/support#report_issues

Comment: Thanks, I have already created a custom web receiver for this and now able to customize everything now with HTML5.